# How can I create Home page of sharepoint site without Login Prompt for Anonymous users?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint site with multiple sub sites when user enter url(http://demosite) homepage should be displayed without login prompt and when i click sign in button the login should be prompted Then i enter username and password it will redirect to corresponding site collection. Please help me how to do this......

Answer (score 4):

Have you enabled all the anonymous users settings? First of, you have to enable access for the web app in central admin (manage web applications, select the web app in the list, click authentication providers in the ribbon, then the active auth provider link in the dialog and check "**enable anonymous access**".

After that, also in the manage web apps page, apply any desired anonymous user policy.

Now, you're not there yet, you now have to enable anonymous access in the site collection itself. You can do this under **site settings** -> **site permissions** -> **anonymous access** in the ribbon. You can now select what an anonymous user can see in your site.

If all goes well, anonymous users should now be able to access your site. There is one hitch though. If you have anything on the homepage (i.e. image, or a web part displaying news items etc.) that access content from a part of the site the user has no access to, he or she will get a login prompt/access denied page.